# É possível configurar um Jquery Effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, toggle

É possível mudar as opções no `Toggle Explode`? Por exemplo: ele tem nove divisões como padrão, é possível modificar o número de partes em que ele explode e o tamanho dessas partes? Também queria saber se o `JQuery` permite a mudança do tamanho da explosão deste efeito, pois no meu caso a `div` sai da página.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode-se escolher o número de partes através da opção `pieces`:

```
$(elemento).toggle("explode", {
    pieces: 25
});
```

O número de peças não precisa ser quadrado, mas segundo [o código-fonte](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/third_party/precajole/jqueryui/1.8.22/ui/jquery.effects.explode.js?r=5006) ele arredondará a raiz quadrada desse número para escolher o número de linhas e de colunas (i.e. os pedaços serão quadrados, com o mesmo número de linhas e colunas - sem pedaços retangulares).

Não há opção de se customizar o tamanho da explosão. Ainda segundo os fontes, o deslocamento é <del>proporcional ao tamanho do pedaço</del> (*Edit:* na verdade ele é mais ou menos o mesmo toda vez; exceto por um pequeno arredondamento, ele vai ocupar  o dobro do espaço do elemento original), e ele sempre explode para fora do seu espaço original (a menos que o número de peças seja 4, caso em que a peça inferior direita não se move).

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/fp6deats/). Se você precisa mesmo que o tamanho da explosão seja menor, eu sugiro definir o seu próprio efeito, usando o código do explode como referência. Basta que no `css` e/ou no `animate` (dependendo de se você está mostrando ou escondendo) você multiplicar o deslocamento final por um fator de sua escolha:

```
var meuFator = 0.2;

...

left: offset.left + j*(width/cells) +
      (o.options.mode == 'show' ? (j-Math.floor(cells/2))*(width/cells)*meuFator : 0),
```

Comment: Pesquisei em vários lugares e percebi que no meu caso, não é possível realizar o que eu desejo, mas sua resposta correta bem explicatória!